# JMSSerializer Bundle no serializa relaciones

Tags: mysql, rest, symfony2, doctrine2, serialización

Controlador :

```
public function newUserAction(Request $request)
{
    $errores = array();
    $usuario = new Usuario();

    $foto = $request->files->get('foto');
    $email = $request->request->get('email');
    $username = $request->request->get('username');
    $pass = $request->request->get('password');

    if ($email == null){
        array_push($errores, 'El Email no puede estar vacío') ;
    }
    if ($pass == null){
        array_push($errores, 'El Password no puede estar vacío') ;
    }
    $helper = $this->get('my_service.helper');

    if (count($errores) == 0){
        $fecha_ahora = new \DateTime("now");

        $usuario->setEmail($email);
        $usuario->setUsername($username);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $perfil = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Perfiles')->find(1);
        $usuario->setPerfil($perfil);

        $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
        $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($usuario);
        $salt = $helper->randomString(25,true,true,true);
        $usuario->setSalt($salt);
        $password = $encoder->encodePassword($pass, $salt);
        $usuario->setPassword($password);

        $confirmationToken = $helper->randomString(30,true,true,true);
        $usuario->setConfirmationToken($confirmationToken);
        $usuario->setFechaRegistro($fecha_ahora);
        $usuario->setFechaUltimoLogin($fecha_ahora);

        if ($foto!= null){
            $helper->guardaFotoUsuario($foto);
        }
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($usuario);
        $em->flush();
    }

    $usuarioPresenter = $helper->getUsuarioPresenter($usuario);
    if (count($errores) > 0){
        foreach ($errores as $error){
            $usuarioPresenter->addError($error);
        }            
    }
    return $usuarioPresenter;

}
```

Entidades usuario y perfiles :

```
<?php

namespace ...\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type;

 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="usuario")
 * 
 */
class Usuario {

    /**
     * @var int
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     **/
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=false)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
     */
    private $confirmationToken;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean",nullable=false)
     */
    private $activo = false;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
     */
    private $sessionId;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true, length=20)
     */
    private $cifDni;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true, length=14)
    */
    private $tlf;

    /**
     * @Type("array")
     * @ORM\Column(name="fechaRegistro", type="datetime",nullable=true)
    **/
    private $fechaRegistro;

    /**
     * @Type("array")
     * @ORM\Column(name="fechaUltimoLogin", type="datetime",nullable=true)
    **/
    private $fechaUltimoLogin;

    //relacion entre el usuario y su perfil
    /**
     * @Type("array")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Perfiles",inversedBy="usuarios")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="perfil", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $perfil;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     *
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get salt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * Set confirmationToken
     *
     * @param string $confirmationToken
     *
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setConfirmationToken($confirmationToken)
    {
        $this->confirmationToken = $confirmationToken;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get confirmationToken
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getConfirmationToken()
    {
        return $this->confirmationToken;
    }

    /**
     * Set activo
     *
     * @param boolean $activo
     *
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setActivo($activo)
    {
        $this->activo = $activo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get activo
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getActivo()
    {
        return $this->activo;
    }

    /**
     * Set sessionId
     *
     * @param string $sessionId
     *
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setSessionId($sessionId)
    {
        $this->sessionId = $sessionId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sessionId
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSessionId()
    {
        return $this->sessionId;
    }

    /**
     * Set cifDni
     *
     * @param string $cifDni
     *
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setCifDni($cifDni)
    {
        $this->cifDni = $cifDni;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cifDni
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCifDni()
    {
        return $this->cifDni;
    }

    /**
     * Set tlf
     *
     * @param string $tlf
     *
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setTlf($tlf)
    {
        $this->tlf = $tlf;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tlf
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTlf()
    {
        return $this->tlf;
    }

    /**
     * Set fechaRegistro
     *
     * @param \DateTime $fechaRegistro
     *
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setFechaRegistro($fechaRegistro)
    {
        $this->fechaRegistro = $fechaRegistro;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fechaRegistro
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getFechaRegistro()
    {
        return $this->fechaRegistro;
    }

    /**
     * Set fechaUltimoLogin
     *
     * @param \DateTime $fechaUltimoLogin
     *
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setFechaUltimoLogin($fechaUltimoLogin)
    {
        $this->fechaUltimoLogin = $fechaUltimoLogin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fechaUltimoLogin
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getFechaUltimoLogin()
    {
        return $this->fechaUltimoLogin;
    }


    /**
     * Set perfil
     *
     * @param \TaurusUrsusApiRest\MainBundle\Entity\Perfiles $perfil
     *
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function setPerfil(\TaurusUrsusApiRest\MainBundle\Entity\Perfiles $perfil = null)
    {
        $this->perfil = $perfil;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get perfil
     *
     * @return \TaurusUrsusApiRest\MainBundle\Entity\Perfiles
     */
    public function getPerfil()
    {
        return $this->perfil;
    }
}


<?php

namespace ...\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Perfil
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Perfiles
{

    /**
    * @var int
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    **/
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="nombrePerfil", type="string", length=250)
    **/
    protected $nombrePerfil;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Usuario", mappedBy="perfil")
     */
    protected $usuarios;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->usuarios = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nombrePerfil
     *
     * @param string $nombrePerfil
     *
     * @return Perfiles
     */
    public function setNombrePerfil($nombrePerfil)
    {
        $this->nombrePerfil = $nombrePerfil;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nombrePerfil
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNombrePerfil()
    {
        return $this->nombrePerfil;
    }

    /**
     * Add usuario
     *
     * @param \TaurusUrsusApiRest\MainBundle\Entity\Usuario $usuario
     *
     * @return Perfiles
     */
    public function addUsuario(\TaurusUrsusApiRest\MainBundle\Entity\Usuario $usuario)
    {
        $this->usuarios[] = $usuario;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove usuario
     *
     * @param \TaurusUrsusApiRest\MainBundle\Entity\Usuario $usuario
     */
    public function removeUsuario(\TaurusUrsusApiRest\MainBundle\Entity\Usuario $usuario)
    {
        $this->usuarios->removeElement($usuario);
    }

    /**
     * Get usuarios
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getUsuarios()
    {
        return $this->usuarios;
    }
}
```

Resuesta JSON :

```
{
    "entity": {
        "email": "postman@envio.es",
        "username": "Usuario desde postman",
        "password": "$2y$13$ZEE1QUB2JGEjcXMzOVcpe.0jx06mmqOQxUzj8f1OxtYhTxmkmHEU.",
        "salt": "dA5A@v$a#qs39W)xzrBLF($oA",
        "confirmation_token": "*Ud0OWeP5_M7;PUXD&(Rpwtcsz3|J&",
        "activo": false,
        "fecha_registro": {
            "date": "2018-01-12 09:57:11.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
        },
        "fecha_ultimo_login": {
            "date": "2018-01-12 09:57:11.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
        },
        "perfil": []
    },
    "ruta_foto": "/imgusers/default/",
    "errores": []
}
```

¿Porque la clase Perfil se me devuelve vacia? ¿alguien puede ayudarme?
otra cosa que me pasa aqui es que las fechas debo devolverlas de tipo array porque si hago esto @Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d'>") me vienen vacias.
¿alguna sugerencia o ayuda? muchas gracias.

Comment: Al crear un nuevo usuario el campo perfil se llena por defecto? No veo que estés seteando el perfil.

Comment: Si,si te fijas esta a la derecha de esta linea : $perfil = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Perfiles')->find(1); solo que el editor se ha comido un intro.Gracias.

Comment: podrías probar haciendo que perfil sea una propiedad pública, o declarando una `JMS\VirtualProperty` sobre `getPerfil`

Comment: Respondo a continuación que aqui no hay editor.

Answer (score 0):

Si pongo a publico $perfil :

```
/**
* @Type("array")
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Perfiles",inversedBy="usuarios")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="perfil", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
public $perfil;
```

la respuesta es la misma con el perfil vacío

Pero si pongo tambien esto :

```
/**
 * @Type("array")
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Usuario", mappedBy="perfil")
 */
public $usuarios;
```

La respuesta es :

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": [
        {
            "message": "Class ArrayCollection does not exist",
           "class": "ReflectionException",
....
....
}
```

}

He de decir que los objetos los devuelvo de tipo array porque ese error de ArrayCollection me da al intentar pasarlo sin poner @Type,y tampoco tengo idea de porque puede ser,en un hilo del creador de JMSSerializerBundle se hablaba de pasarlos como array y me ha funcionado con las fechas,pero con relaciones nada.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

si uso virtualproperty    :

```
<?php

namespace ....\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
//use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
//use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\VirtualProperty;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;

 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="usuario")
 *
 * @VirtualProperty(
 *     "perfil",
 *     exp="object.getPerfil()",
 *     options={@SerializedName("perfil")}
 *  )
 * 
 */
class Usuario {

/**
 * @var int
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 **/
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=false)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=false)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
 */
private $salt;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
 */
private $confirmationToken;

/**
 * @var boolean
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean",nullable=false)
 */
private $activo = false;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
 */
private $sessionId;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true, length=20)
 */
private $cifDni;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true, length=14)
*/
private $tlf;

/**
 * @Type("array")
 * @ORM\Column(name="fechaRegistro", type="datetime",nullable=true)
**/
private $fechaRegistro;

/**
 * @Type("array")
 * @ORM\Column(name="fechaUltimoLogin", type="datetime",nullable=true)
**/

//        * @Type("DateTime<'d-m-Y H:i:s'>")

private $fechaUltimoLogin;

//relacion entre el usuario y su perfil
/**
 * @Type("array")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Perfiles",inversedBy="usuarios")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="perfil", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $perfil;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set username
 *
 * @param string $username
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get username
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get password
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Set salt
 *
 * @param string $salt
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setSalt($salt)
{
    $this->salt = $salt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get salt
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSalt()
{
    return $this->salt;
}

/**
 * Set confirmationToken
 *
 * @param string $confirmationToken
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setConfirmationToken($confirmationToken)
{
    $this->confirmationToken = $confirmationToken;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get confirmationToken
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getConfirmationToken()
{
    return $this->confirmationToken;
}

/**
 * Set activo
 *
 * @param boolean $activo
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setActivo($activo)
{
    $this->activo = $activo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get activo
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getActivo()
{
    return $this->activo;
}

/**
 * Set sessionId
 *
 * @param string $sessionId
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setSessionId($sessionId)
{
    $this->sessionId = $sessionId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get sessionId
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSessionId()
{
    return $this->sessionId;
}

/**
 * Set cifDni
 *
 * @param string $cifDni
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setCifDni($cifDni)
{
    $this->cifDni = $cifDni;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get cifDni
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCifDni()
{
    return $this->cifDni;
}

/**
 * Set tlf
 *
 * @param string $tlf
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setTlf($tlf)
{
    $this->tlf = $tlf;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tlf
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTlf()
{
    return $this->tlf;
}

/**
 * Set fechaRegistro
 *
 * @param \DateTime $fechaRegistro
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setFechaRegistro($fechaRegistro)
{
    $this->fechaRegistro = $fechaRegistro;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fechaRegistro
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getFechaRegistro()
{
    return $this->fechaRegistro;
}

/**
 * Set fechaUltimoLogin
 *
 * @param \DateTime $fechaUltimoLogin
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setFechaUltimoLogin($fechaUltimoLogin)
{
    $this->fechaUltimoLogin = $fechaUltimoLogin;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fechaUltimoLogin
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getFechaUltimoLogin()
{
    return $this->fechaUltimoLogin;
}


/**
 * Set perfil
 *
 * @param \TaurusUrsusApiRest\MainBundle\Entity\Perfiles $perfil
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setPerfil(\TaurusUrsusApiRest\MainBundle\Entity\Perfiles $perfil = null)
{
    $this->perfil = $perfil;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get perfil
 * @VirtualProperty()
 * @return \TaurusUrsusApiRest\MainBundle\Entity\Perfiles
 */
public function getPerfil()
{
    return $this->perfil;
}
}
```

la respuesta cambia un poco,pero no mucho :

```
{
"entity": {
    "perfil": [],
    "id": 52,
    "email": "postman@envio.es",
    "username": "Usuario desde postman",
    "password": "$2y$13$ZkJ2TSYxezB4NiVzVyotduWbifzUEcl6o0lnZJwWPKSk8uBL.bB7e",
    "salt": "fBvM&1{0x6%sW*-wH2;4y)6#6",
    "confirmation_token": "wSUccqb)^0y_yw3J}YEqypZ#=~x9k3",
    "activo": false,
    "fecha_registro": {
        "date": "2018-01-12 15:43:50.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
    },
    "fecha_ultimo_login": {
        "date": "2018-01-12 15:43:50.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
    }
},
"ruta_foto": "/imgusers/default/",
"errores": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno pues lo he conseguido con VirtualProperty :

```
namespace TaurusUrsusApiRest\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
//use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
//use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\VirtualProperty;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Exclude;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;

 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="usuario")
 *
 * @VirtualProperty(
 *     "perfil",
 *     exp="object.getPerfil()",
 *     options={@SerializedName("perfil")}
 *  )
 * 
 */
class Usuario {

/**
 * @var int
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 **/
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=false)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=false)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
 */
private $salt;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
 */
private $confirmationToken;

/**
 * @var boolean
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean",nullable=false)
 */
private $activo = false;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
 */
private $sessionId;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true, length=20)
 */
private $cifDni;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true, length=14)
*/
private $tlf;

/**
 * @Type("array")
 * @ORM\Column(name="fechaRegistro", type="datetime",nullable=true)
**/
private $fechaRegistro;

/**
 * @Type("array")
 * @ORM\Column(name="fechaUltimoLogin", type="datetime",nullable=true)
**/

//        * @Type("DateTime<'d-m-Y H:i:s'>")

private $fechaUltimoLogin;

//relacion entre el usuario y su perfil
/**
 * @Exclude
 * @Type("array")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Perfiles",inversedBy="usuarios")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="perfil", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $perfil;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set username
 *
 * @param string $username
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get username
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get password
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Set salt
 *
 * @param string $salt
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setSalt($salt)
{
    $this->salt = $salt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get salt
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSalt()
{
    return $this->salt;
}

/**
 * Set confirmationToken
 *
 * @param string $confirmationToken
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setConfirmationToken($confirmationToken)
{
    $this->confirmationToken = $confirmationToken;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get confirmationToken
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getConfirmationToken()
{
    return $this->confirmationToken;
}

/**
 * Set activo
 *
 * @param boolean $activo
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setActivo($activo)
{
    $this->activo = $activo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get activo
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getActivo()
{
    return $this->activo;
}

/**
 * Set sessionId
 *
 * @param string $sessionId
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setSessionId($sessionId)
{
    $this->sessionId = $sessionId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get sessionId
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSessionId()
{
    return $this->sessionId;
}

/**
 * Set cifDni
 *
 * @param string $cifDni
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setCifDni($cifDni)
{
    $this->cifDni = $cifDni;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get cifDni
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCifDni()
{
    return $this->cifDni;
}

/**
 * Set tlf
 *
 * @param string $tlf
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setTlf($tlf)
{
    $this->tlf = $tlf;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tlf
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTlf()
{
    return $this->tlf;
}

/**
 * Set fechaRegistro
 *
 * @param \DateTime $fechaRegistro
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setFechaRegistro($fechaRegistro)
{
    $this->fechaRegistro = $fechaRegistro;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fechaRegistro
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getFechaRegistro()
{
    return $this->fechaRegistro;
}

/**
 * Set fechaUltimoLogin
 *
 * @param \DateTime $fechaUltimoLogin
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setFechaUltimoLogin($fechaUltimoLogin)
{
    $this->fechaUltimoLogin = $fechaUltimoLogin;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fechaUltimoLogin
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getFechaUltimoLogin()
{
    return $this->fechaUltimoLogin;
}


/**
 * Set perfil
 *
 * @param \TaurusUrsusApiRest\MainBundle\Entity\Perfiles $perfil
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setPerfil(\TaurusUrsusApiRest\MainBundle\Entity\Perfiles $perfil = null)
{
    $this->perfil = $perfil;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get perfil
 * @VirtualProperty()
 * @return \TaurusUrsusApiRest\MainBundle\Entity\Perfiles
 */
public function getPerfil()
{
    return $this->perfil;
}
}
```

He tenido que poner * @Exclude en la relación $perfil,debe ser que no pueden tener nombres iguales la variable de la relación y el nombre del VirtualProperty

Si le cambio el nombre a la VirtualProperty y la llamo perfilUsu,funciona tambien,pero devuelve el perfil por partida doble :

```
{
"entity": {
    "perfilUsu": {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre_perfil": "Admin",
        "usuarios": [
            {
                "id": 52,
                "email": "postman@envio.es",
                "username": "Usuario desde postman",
                "password": "$2y$13$ZkJ2TSYxezB4NiVzVyotduWbifzUEcl6o0lnZJwWPKSk8uBL.bB7e",
                "salt": "fBvM&1{0x6%sW*-wH2;4y)6#6",
                "confirmation_token": "wSUccqb)^0y_yw3J}YEqypZ#=~x9k3",
                "activo": false,
                "fecha_registro": {
                    "date": "2018-01-12 15:43:50.000000",
                    "timezone_type": 3,
                    "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
                },
                "fecha_ultimo_login": {
                    "date": "2018-01-12 15:43:50.000000",
                    "timezone_type": 3,
                    "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "perfil": {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre_perfil": "Admin",
        "usuarios": [
            {
                "id": 52,
                "email": "postman@envio.es",
                "username": "Usuario desde postman",
                "password": "$2y$13$ZkJ2TSYxezB4NiVzVyotduWbifzUEcl6o0lnZJwWPKSk8uBL.bB7e",
                "salt": "fBvM&1{0x6%sW*-wH2;4y)6#6",
                "confirmation_token": "wSUccqb)^0y_yw3J}YEqypZ#=~x9k3",
                "activo": false,
                "fecha_registro": {
                    "date": "2018-01-12 15:43:50.000000",
                    "timezone_type": 3,
                    "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
                },
                "fecha_ultimo_login": {
                    "date": "2018-01-12 15:43:50.000000",
                    "timezone_type": 3,
                    "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "email": "postman@envio.es",
    "username": "Usuario desde postman",
    "password": "$2y$13$VWVJWSl5RyR.IypMdyV0MeUPC/RvZbJo5ioWyTayaMx/Fv0pc.8ni",
    "salt": "UeIY)yG$~#*Lw%t2dJrDwPkc*",
    "confirmation_token": "69WNGm}M41pQ~XEt30W1iS}zY-%|{&",
    "activo": false,
    "fecha_registro": {
        "date": "2018-01-12 16:08:27.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
    },
    "fecha_ultimo_login": {
        "date": "2018-01-12 16:08:27.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
    }
},
"ruta_foto": "/imgusers/default/",
"errores": []
}
```

Muchas gracias amenadiel me has abierto los ojos.